# How to Make a Uniform Random Integer Generator from a Random Boolean Generator?

Tags: kotlin, random, probability, probability-theory

I have a hardware-based boolean generator that generates either 1 or 0 uniformly. How to use it to make a uniform 8-bit integer generator? I'm currently using the collected booleans to create the binary string for the 8-bit integer. The generated integers aren't uniformly distributed. It follows the distribution explained on [this page](http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/152.mf1i.spring02/RandomWalk.htm). Integers with ̶a̶ ̶l̶o̶t̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶a̶l̶t̶e̶r̶n̶a̶t̶I̶n̶g̶ ̶b̶I̶t̶s̶ the same number of 1's and 0's such as 85 (01010101) and -86 (10101010) have the highest chance to be generated and integers with a lot of repeating bits such as 0 (00000000) and -1 (11111111) have the lowest chance.

Here's the page that I've annotated with probabilities for each possible 4-bit integer. We can see that they're not uniform. 3, 5, 6, -7, -6, and -4 that have the same number of 1's and 0's have ⁶/₁₆ probability while 0 and -1 that all of their bits are the same only have ¹/₁₆ probability.

[image: annotated page].

And here's [my implementation on Kotlin](https://gist.github.com/awasisto/ea60b86bf0c619bfe689a461e0fd7f1f#file-rng-kt-L49-L75)

Comment: I recommend editing that info into your question. Good question.

Comment: If your bit source is biased, then you need to look at a de-skewing technique.  [RFC 4086](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4086) gives some suggestions.  The von Neumann technique (see section 4.2 of the RFC) is simple, though there are others.  To some extent you have to fit the de-skewing technique to the particular biases of your bit source.

Comment: @rossum Its shannon entropy is 0.99916596. It passes all 114 dieharder tests. One of them is regarded as weak. What kind of deskewing method do you think is the best for my case?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but the description is still unclear. You should state explicitly how you are constructing the integer from bits. You should also be specific about the distribution of the generated integers -- there is a lot of stuff on the linked-to page, so it's unreasonable to expect others to try to figure which of several things you might be talking about.

Comment: @RobertDodier Sorry. I've annotated the page. I hope it's a little bit clearer now

Comment: All of the 16 possible outcomes are mutually exclusive, you'll only get one of them when you draw a 4 bit sample.  Hence your handwritten table violates the requirement that all of the mutually exclusive probabilities sum to 1, and thus it cannot possibly be correct.

Comment: It looks like you're calculating the probabilities associated with the number of 1-bits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) rather than the probabilities of getting each outcome.  These are two entirely different things.  If the bits are independent and equally likely to yield 0/1, then all of the 16 combinations have probability 1/16.

Comment: Why is the probability of getting 01010101 higher than 00000000? This makes no sense to me.

Comment: @MartinWickman Both 01010101 and 00000000 are equally likely.  However, getting four 1's out of eight is more likely than getting zero 1's.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your edit, there appears to be a misunderstanding here. By "uniform 4-bit integers", you seem to have the following in mind:

1. Start at 0.
2. Generate a random bit. If it's 1, add 1, and otherwise subtract 1.
3. Repeat step 2 three more times.
4. Output the resulting number.

Although the random bit generator may generate bits where each outcome is as likely as the other to be randomly generated, and each 4-bit chunk may be just as likely as any other to be randomly generated, the number of bits in each chunk is not uniformly distributed.

What range of integers do you want? Say you're generating 4-bit integers. Do you want a range of [-4, 4], as in the 4-bit random walk in your question, or do you want a range of [-8, 7], which is what you get when you treat a 4-bit chunk of bits as a two's complement integer?

If the former, the random walk won't generate a uniform distribution, and you will need to tackle the problem in a different way.

In this case, to generate a uniform random number in the range [-4, 4], do the following:

1. Take 4 bits of the random bit generator and treat them as an integer in [0, 15);
2. If the integer is greater than 8, go to step 1.
3. Subtract 4 from the integer and output it.

This algorithm uses *rejection sampling*, but is variable-time (thus is not appropriate whenever timing differences can be exploited in a security attack). Numbers in other ranges are similarly generated, but the details are too involved to describe in this answer. See my article on [random number generation methods](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html) for details.

---

Based on the code you've shown me, your approach to building up `byte`s, `int`s, and `long`s is highly error-prone.  For example, a better way to build up an 8-bit byte to achieve what you want is as follows (keeping in mind that I am not very familiar with Kotlin, so the syntax may be wrong):

```
val i = 0
val b = 0
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
   b = b << 1; // Shift old bits
   if (bitStringBuilder[i] == '1') {
      b = b | 1; // Set new bit
   } else {
      b = b | 0; // Don't set new bit
   }
}
value = (b as byte) as T
```

Also, if `MediatorLiveData` is not thread safe, then neither is your approach to gathering bits using a `StringBuilder` (especially because `StringBuilder` is not thread safe).

---

<s>The approach you suggest,</s>  combining eight bits of the boolean generator to make one uniform integer, will work in theory. However, in practice there are several issues:

- You don't mention what kind of hardware it is. In most cases, the hardware won't be likely to generate uniformly random Boolean bits unless the hardware is a so-called *true random number generator* designed for this purpose. For example, the hardware might generate uniformly distributed bits but have periodic behavior.
- *Entropy* means how hard it is to predict the values a generator produces, compared to ideal random values. For example, a 64-bit data block with 32 bits of entropy is as hard to predict as an ideal random 32-bit data block. Characterizing a hardware device's entropy (or ability to produce unpredictable values) is far from trivial. Among other things, this involves entropy tests that have to be done across the full range of operating conditions suitable for the hardware (e.g., temperature, voltage).
- Most hardware cannot produce uniform random values, so usually an additional step, called *randomness extraction*, *entropy extraction*, *unbiasing*, *whitening*, or *deskewing*, is done to transform the values the hardware generates into uniformly distributed random numbers. However, it works best if the hardware's entropy is characterized first (see previous point).
- Finally, you still have to test whether the whole process delivers numbers that are "adequately random" for your purposes. There are several statistical tests that attempt to do so, such as NIST's Statistical Test Suite or TestU01.

For more information, see "[Nondeterministic Sources and Seed Generation](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Nondeterministic_Sources_and_Seed_Generation)".

---

After your edits to this page, it seems you're going about the problem the wrong way. To produce a uniform random number, you don't *add* uniformly distributed random bits (e.g., `bit() + bit() + bit()`), but *concatenate* them (e.g., `(bit() << 2) | (bit() << 1) | bit()`). However, again, this will work in theory, but not in practice, for the reasons I mention above.

Comment: Yes, I concatenated the bits instead of adding them. The randomness is gathered from the shot noise of a pixel on my phone camera so technically it's a quantum RNG. Its shannon entropy is 0.99916596. It also passes all 114 dieharder tests. One of them is regarded as weak though. I'm not sure if my method is good enough because some numbers are generated more often than the others. If I'm generating standard 32-bit integers, 0 and 1 will never ever be generated because my boolean generator would never repeatedly generate a same bit for 32 times. What kind of unbiasing method do you suggest?

Comment: For random number generation purposes, min-entropy is more appropriate than Shannon entropy.  Also, there are many unbiasing techniques available: von Neumann, HMAC-SHA512, and others.  (For example, Cliff/Boyd/Gonzalez in 2009 reviewed HMAC as a randomness extractor.) Also note that although the underlying bit generator may be uniform, a random walk distribution from that generator is far from uniform.

Comment: That's the problem I'm trying to solve. Is there a way to make the random walk distribution from the bit generator more uniform? Does unbiasing solve that problem? I can make the generated integer as a seed of a PRNG. The random walk distribution should be more uniform. But I'm not sure if it's a good idea since the generated numbers will be more predictable

Comment: The page you linked to says: "If it’s heads, you take one step forward.  If it’s tails, you take one step back." Put another way: "If the bit is 0, add 1.  If the bit is 1, subtract 1."  You start at 0, then add or subtract 1 from it depending on the outcome of each of eight bits, then give back the result.  This number can range from -8 to 8.  That is far from being a uniform distribution. (If that is not what you mean, please edit your question and detail how you are forming random numbers with your bit generator, what results you're getting (with examples), and what results you expect.)

Comment: On the other hand, a "uniform random walk", as you seem to want, is also called "white noise".  For this kind of walk, just take 8-bit chunks from the random bit generator and treat each of them as the two's-complement form of an 8-bit integer.

Comment: I've annotated the page with probabilities for each possible 4-bit integer. You can see that they're not uniform

Comment: I don't add/subtract the bits. I concatenate them and they're not uniform. How can they be uniform when integers with the same number of 1's and 0's have higher probabilities? Here's my implementation using Kotlin: https://gist.github.com/awasisto/ea60b86bf0c619bfe689a461e0fd7f1f#file-rng-kt-L49-L75

Comment: And here's a small sample of the booleans generated using my hardware-based RNG https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lmiFjT2qs14q0ykONd9e1djTKBYrMC06/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have edited my answer.  And by the way, the fact that chunks of bits can have a nonuniform number of bits, even if the chunks are uniformly distributed, is an interesting paradox in probability theory.  If you want to know more, you should ask a question about that fact in math.stackexchange.com, and compare the _uniform distribution_ with the _uniform sum distribution_.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the concurrency problem. I'll synchronize the entire block. What kind of error does my approach of building the bytes, ints, and longs prone to?

Comment: Your current approach is more complicated than it has to be to extract `byte`s, `int`s, and `long`s from a string of bits, making it prone to unexpected logic errors such as the one you're suffering with (involving the distribution of the bits).  Did you try the code I suggested in my answer?

Comment: Mine and yours [return the same outputs](https://ideone.com/T1NwJg) but yours needs more casts when generating bytes because JVM languages can't do bitwise operations on `byte`. I think it's okay that the generated numbers aren't so uniform since in most cases we only need to generate bounded numbers

Comment: In any case, the fact remains that random chunks of bits can have a nonuniform number of set bits, even if the chunks are independent and uniformly distributed.  It sounds that this is a paradox in probability theory that is counterintuitive to you.  If you need more help understanding this, this site is the wrong place to do so; try asking in math.stackexchange.com instead. Also, I have already given you pointers in my answer on how to generate integers in an arbitrary integer range.